# Computing eigen vectors in order to extract Jordan Canonical form

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So , I am trying to learn the jordan canonica form . In my class , we proved that a matrix $A_{n x n}$
can be written in the form $A = UJU^{-1}$ where $J$ is the jordan matrix and $U$ is the matrix with the eigen vectors.
I am currently studying an example where:
A is a $3 x 3$ matrix with $\lambda_1=1$ with algebraic multiplicity 3.

The first one - $v_i$ is the right - eigen vector that satisfies $(A-I)v_i=0 \rightarrow a + 2b + c = 0$ (1)
where we noted   as $v_1=(a,b,c)$

as for the second one my teacher said that is the "generalised" first order eigen vector that satisfies :
$(A-I)v_2=v_1 \rightarrow v_1 \in Im(A-I)$ . We found that $Im(A-I) = { (d,d,-d)}$ vectors and he said to as that $v_1$ satisfies this form , which makes sense since $v_1 \in Im(A-I)$ .
**What I  do not   I get** is why $v_2$ should satisfiy (1) as he said.
After , he also said that $v_3$ should satisfiy (1).
Why do $v_2$ and $v_3$ $\in ker(A-I)$ ??

*update*: I thought about it a little bit more: maybe $v_2$ has to satisfiy (1) because $v_1$ does so , so if we do multiply by $(A-I)^{-1}$ (1) we should get that $v_2$ satisfies (1) (?)

Comment: Do you mean the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda_1$ is $3$? Otherwise, how do you know there are 3 eigenvectors?

Comment: no its the algebraic , since AU = UJ , U has to be n x 1 , doesn't it? in order to be able to be multiplied

Comment: @paulinho anyway i deleted that comment , because it is not my current question / problem, you may be right, but there is no chance to have more than 3 , i guess because after we found out that $(A-I)^3 =0$ matrix

Comment: $U$ can be $n \times n$. If the algebraic multiplicity is less than $3$, then you will have real generalized eigenvectors. But those generalized eigenvectors $v$ don't necessarily satisfy $(A - I) v = 0$.

Comment: Generalized eigenvectors *aren't* eigenvectors; in particular, in your example, if the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $1$ is $1$, then there will be two independent generalized eigenvectors, which aren't in the kernel of $A-I$, but they are in the kernel of $(A-I)^k$ for some $k$. For the simplest possible example, consider $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. An eigenvector of this matrix with eigenvalue $0$ is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$. A generalized eigenvector associated to that eigenvalue is $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.